# Progress bar in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a shiny dashboard where user can send emails. Once he clicks on `Send Email` button, I wanna show the user progress of email sending. Currently I am using following code in which progress bar gets executed first and then email sending starts.

```
observeEvent(input$send_email, {
final_data <- loadData()
city <- input$city_select
country <- input$country_select
email_type <- input$email_select
start_date <-  format(input$dateRange[1])
end_date <- format(input$dateRange[2])
from <- as.integer(input$from)
to <- as.integer(input$to)

progress <- Progress$new(session, min=1, max=15)
on.exit(progress$close())

progress$set(message = 'Sending Emails',
             detail = 'This may take a while...')

for (i in 1:to) {
  progress$set(value = i)
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}

email_data <- final_data[final_data$registrant_city == city & (final_data$create_date >= start_date & final_data$create_date <= end_date),]
emails<- quick_email(email_data,city,country)
emails <- emails[from:to]

send_email(emails,input$subject_select)

session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'testmessage',
                          message = paste0('Emails have been successfully sent to ',city,' region,please update the excel sheet.'))


})
```

`send_email` function sends the emails to desired recipients. Where shall I place the progress bar code so that it starts as soon as email sending starts.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you out...

```
observeEvent(input$send_email, {
  req(input$email_select) # you dont want to send with out selecting any emails
  final_data <- loadData()
  city <- input$city_select
  country <- input$country_select
  email_type <- input$email_select
  start_date <-  format(input$dateRange[1])
  end_date <- format(input$dateRange[2])
  from <- as.integer(input$from)
  to <- as.integer(input$to)

  # I would prefer the withProgress 
  withProgress(value = 0,message = 'Sending Emails',
               detail = 'This may take a while...'{
                 email_data <- final_data[final_data$registrant_city == city & (final_data$create_date >= start_date & final_data$create_date <= end_date),]
                 incProgress(amount = .2, message = "Add you message or ignore") #Add you message or ignore
                 emails<- quick_email(email_data,city,country)
                 incProgress(amount = .4, message = "Add you message or ignore") #Add you message or ignore
                 emails <- emails[from:to]
                 incProgress(amount = .7, message = "Almost done") #Add you message or ignore
                 send_email(emails,input$subject_select)
                 incProgress(amount = 1, message = "Done Here") #Add you message or ignore
               })
  session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'testmessage',
                            message = paste0('Emails have been successfully sent to ',city,' region,please update the excel sheet.'))


})
```